# Guion en objeto c#

Tags: c#

Buenas estoy haciendo una petición POST en C# y recibo la siguiente respuesta:

```
 "resp": {
        "clave": "50623081800310267146900100001010000000135127983503",
        "fecha": "2018-08-31T18:05:54-06:00",
        "ind-estado": "aceptado",
        "respuesta-xml": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i    
}
```

Quiero obtener el código de `ind-estado`

```
IRestResponse response2 = client.Execute(request);
 dynamic x= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response2.Content);

richTextBox1.Text = " " + x.resp.fecha;
```

///////////ESO ME FUNCIONA PARA OBTENER LA FECHA. EL PROBLEMA ES QUE CUANDO QUIERO

Eso me funciona para obtener la fecha, el problema, es cuando quiero obtener el `x.resp.ind-estado`  y agregarlo al `RichTextBox`, Visual Studio marca un error de sintaxis

> El nombre `estado` no existe en el contexto actual

¿Como puedo solucionarlo ?

Comment: Podrias mostrar como queda el objeto completo una vez deserializado? y porque usas dynamic??? y porque no tenes una interfaz para directamente transformarlo a eso?

Answer (score 3):

Tu problema, se da porque C# no puede diferenciar entre un nombre con guión y una resta.

Por lo cual,utilizando [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) ,  para solucionar tu problema, primero, debes mapear el formato de tu Json en una clase, y luego, debes utilizar la anotación `[JsonProperty]` para decirle a C# que mapee correctamente la propiedad.

Empecemos, primero, escribimos las clase, con su correspondiente anotación

```
public class Resp
{
    public string clave { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ind-estado")]
    public string indEstado { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "respuesta-xml")]
    public string respuestaXML { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Resp resp { get; set; }
}
```

Como se puede ver, utilizamos la anotación `JsonProperty` para decirle, que en lugar de esperar `indEstado`, espere `ind-estado`

Luego, sólo bastaría, deserializarlo como `RootObject` en lugar de `dynamic`

```
    class Program
    {
        //Defino el response como un string para el ejemplo
        const string response = @"{" +
" \"resp\": {" +
"        \"clave\": \"50623081800310267146900100001010000000135127983503\"," +
"        \"fecha\": \"2018-08-31T18:05:54-06:00\"," +
"        \"ind-estado\": \"aceptado\"," +
"        \"respuesta-xml\": \"PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0i\"   " +
"}" +
"}";


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RootObject a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response);

            Console.WriteLine(a.resp.indEstado);
            Console.WriteLine(a.resp.respuestaXML);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
```

Te dejo un [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sRGClh) con lo que te explico funcionando

Saludos!